# Avoid JSON removing child object

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

I'm writing a Spring application with Hibernate framework.

In my application there is a JSON call. In that JSON response returns object hierarchy like below:

- Object

  - SupplyBatch

    - Farmer

This farmer has attributes such as ID, Name, Address and contact.

First object of array list it returns all there attributes and child objects are filled with relevant data. But the problem is that farmer is in second or third or in any other supply batch, that farmer is returned as an attribute in supply batch called "Farmer" with value of farmer's ID.

But when I loop that object in controller it print all the farmer's name. I can't figure out what is this behavior. Here are the screenshots of sample objects.

[image: First object with all the child objects]

[image: Second object with farmer's ID without farmer object]

This is the json response in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"admin/getTaskByDate","user/getTaskByDate"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Task> getTaskByDate(@RequestParam("date") String date) {


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dat = null;
    try {
        dat = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Task> tasksByDate = taskService.getFeedIssueTasksByDate(dat);

    for(Task t : tasksByDate)
    {
        System.out.println("Farmers-"+t.getSupplyBatch().getFarmer().getName());
    }



    return tasksByDate;

}
```

and following is the code in jsp page which calls this json response

```
<script>
function getTaskById(){
var date = $('#inputDate').val();

$("#tblTask").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

var sid = this.value;
$.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/jp/user/getTaskByDate.json?date='+date+'',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data[i];

                    var act;



                    var dt = new Date(obj.duedate);

                    if(obj.type == "Feed Issuing")
                        {
                            act='<td><a href="./addBatchFeed.html?tid='+obj.taskId+'&bid='+obj.supplyBatch.supplyBatchId+'" class="btn btn-primary">Issue Feed</a></td>'
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        act='<td><a href="./addCatching.html?tid='+obj.taskId+'&bid='+obj.batch+'" class="btn btn-primary">Catch</a></td>';
                        }

                    $('#tblTask tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+obj.taskId+'</td><td>'+dt+'</td><td>'+obj.status+
                            '</td><td>'+obj.supplyBatch.supplyBatchId+'</td><td>'+obj.supplyBatch.farmer.name+'</td><td>'+obj.feedType+'</td><td>'+obj.quantity+'</td>'+act+'</tr>');
                }

            }

        });
return false;

}
```

Comment: Please post your code which is printing that you don't intend.

Comment: Hi, I added the code in controller and jsp page, Thank you .

Comment: if you are asking why the farmer name is being printed in your controller it's because you have a system print out statement unless I am missing something!!

Comment: Yes I know.my question is why that object has been removed from the json response? if you refer to screenshots you can see it

Comment: Can u please print the Json response in your controller and see if it is correct

Comment: Yes, I was able to print all the farmers in my controller.all these records has been fetched from the database correctly.what I think happening is in json call it removes the duplicate farmer objects and just keep the id of the farmer.

Comment: Do all the farmers share the same info except the id in your db?

Comment: no. ID is a auto increment field and other details will be different based on entering details.

Comment: Not sure then Try using Jackson and see if resolves it I am have scenarios but diff entities and it works for me . Also as per your comment you said "will be different " but can you confirm whatever data exists in our table is diff or does any data exists at all